# "Parent must exist" and "No template found for CommentsController#create, rendering head :no_content" Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a weird error with a "New Comment" form.

First, when I submit the comment- I get a popup to save a file (there is no file to save).

[image: chrome popup]
However, the comment is not creating because my app thinks that one of the comment's attributes must exist, when it doesn't need to.

This is my error when submitting:

```
errors: ["Parent must exist"]
No template found for Events::CommentsController#create, rendering head :no_content
```

(However, when you submit a comment with a head, it works as expected)

comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Your comment was successfully saved."
      redirect_to @commentable
    else
      puts "errors: #{@comment.errors.full_messages}"
      flash[:danger] = "Uh Oh"
    end
  end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.string "commentable_type"
    t.bigint "commentable_id"
  end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Comment"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

new_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-6">
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "", style: "height: 200px;" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-3">
      <%= f.submit "add comment", class: "btn btn-light ", id: "submit-comment" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I get a popup to save a file"? Nothing in the code you've shown is a "popup", nor is there any code about a "file", nor have you shared the corresponding view code.

Comment: ...From your edit, are you now saying that you want the `parent` to be optional? In that case, you need `belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Comment", optional: true`

Comment: Good points. Will attach a screenshot of the pop-up & the view code to the question. & Will add  `optional: true`, thought shouldn't it be default for an int in a SQL table?

Comment: It's not "required in SQL", unless you make it a foreign key constraint. Which you haven't. It **is**, however, as of rails 5, a required field as an application validation rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 5 makes `belongs_to` association required by default - there's a great article about it [here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html).

Basically, you just need to mark your `belongs_to` relationship as optional:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Comment", optional: true
```

Comment: Solves the problem though doesn't explain the weird behavior when there is an error. Thanks to both you & Tom_lord